# Hide elements using selenium webdriver in python by executing a javascript

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver

I want to hide elements on canvas element by executing a `javascript` in `python`.

I have tried below:

```
    def hide_elements():
        driver = LiveLibrary.get_webdriver_instance()

        js_script = '''\
        element1 = document.getElementsByClassName('someclass');
        element1[0].style.display = 'none';
        element2 = document.getElementsByClassName('another');
        element2[0].style.display = 'none';
        element3 = document.getElementsByClassName('highlight');
        element3[0].style.display = 'none';
        element4 = document.getElementsByClassName('overlay');
        element4[0].style.display = 'none';
        '''
        driver.execute_script(js_script)
```

The above works but as you can see there is a repetition of code. Is there a way I can simplify this rather than finding each element and hiding them?

Comment: This would work in a browser: `[...document.querySelectorAll("[class^=class]")].forEach(ele => ele.style.display = "none");`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If only one of each class - I use ES<5 to not break your webdriver:

```
var cls = ["someclass","another","highlight","overlay"];
for (var i=0;i<cls.length;i++) {
  document.querySelector("."+cls[i]).style.display = "none";
}
```

This would work in a browser:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll("[class^=class]")].forEach(ele => ele.style.display = "none");
```

For different classes:

```
["someclass","another","highlight","overlay"]
  .forEach(cls => [...document.querySelectorAll("."+cls)]
  .forEach(ele => ele.style.display = "none"));
```

For older JS versions:

```
["someclass","another","highlight","overlay"]
  .forEach(function(cls) { [...document.querySelectorAll("."+cls)]
  .forEach(function(ele) { ele.style.display = "none"})});
```

Even older:

```
var cls= ["someclass","another","highlight","overlay"];
for (var i=0;i<cls.length;i++) {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll("."+cls[i]);
  for (var j=0;j<elements.length;j++) {
    elements[j].style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Comment: Why added answer when you prefer to comment and help OP

Comment: i get this error  webdriverexception: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '=>'

Comment: Yeah, I would expect the version of JS would not allow that. see update

Answer (score 0):

**use following code :**

```
js_script = '''\
document.getElementsByClassName('someclass')[0].setAttribute("hidden","");
document.getElementsByClassName('another')[0].setAttribute("hidden","");
document.getElementsByClassName('highlight')[0].setAttribute("hidden","");
document.getElementsByClassName('overlay')[0].setAttribute("hidden","");
 '''
driver.execute_script(js_script)
```

Comment: More or less same repetition, no?

Comment: @mplungjan : I am just trying to answer the question ..as he specifically mentioned the scripts to be executed..

Comment: @someuser2491 : could you please have a try at this

Comment: There is very little difference between original question and this answer. Instead of display, you set hidden and you save a line by adding the [0] to the getElementsByClassName. Not sure what is gained here DRY-wise